Euclidean norm of a vector resulting from a matrix multiplied by an orthonormal matrix multiplied by an arbitrary vector!
Let $A \in \{0,1\}^{m\times n}$ be a binary matrix with $ m < n$, and let $U \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be an arbitrary orthonormal matrix. Let $\sigma_{min}$ denote the smallest non-zero singular value of $A$, and let $ x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an arbitrary vector. Then does the following inequality hold?
$$\frac{1}{\sigma_{min}} \lvert \lvert Ax \rvert \rvert_2 \leq \lvert \lvert A U x \rvert \rvert_2, \ \forall{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1) $$
If the inequality (1) holds then how can it be proved? If (1) doesn’t hold then what are the conditions $A$ must satisfy so that (1) holds? Your help will be very much appreciated!

No, this does not generally hold. The only examples of $A$ where this does hold that I can think of is where every row and column contains at most one 1-entry.

Actually, in generally it can only hold that $|Ax|_2 \leq |AUx|_2$ for arbitrary $x \in \Bbb R^n$ and arbitrary unitary matrices $U$ if $|Ax|_2$ is constant for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$, which occurs if and only if $A^TA$ is a multiple of the identity matrix, which is impossible in the case that $m < n$.

In other words, not only is it the case that the inequality holds, there actually exists no $A$ satisfying your requirements for which the inequality holds.

@BenGrossmann, will you turn these comments into an answer?

@Sammy I am reluctant to do so without feedback from the asker. The trivial nature of the answer makes me think that there might be a mistake in the framing of the question

@BenGrossmann ; I made a small correction in my question. Please see if you can help.

@DrimitiveWatson It's not clear why you believe that this change should make a difference. Note that $\sigma_\min$ might be less than $1$, in which case the failure of the previous version of your inequality to hold makes it so that your new inequality also fails to hold since you have increased the left hand side

@DrimitiveWatson As an example, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&1\0&0&1}
$$
which has non-zero singular values $(\sqrt{5} \pm 1)/2$
